# apply hover state to desktop version (no tablets and phones) only using media queries

Tags: html, css, ipad, less, media-queries

I am applying hover state styling to a div like this:

```
 div {    

     &:hover {
            color: red !important;
            border: 3px solid red !important;
        }
 }
```

Now, i do not want to apply this css style to ipads and other tablets. So, i added a media query like this

```
   div {   

      @media only screen {

         &:hover {
                color: red !important;
                border: 3px solid red !important;
            }

        }
     }
```

I also tried this

```
div {   

  @media not handheld {

     &:hover {
            color: red !important;
            border: 3px solid red !important;
        }

    }
 }
```

But, the hover styling still gets applied on ipad.
I am new to media queries.

Any idea how can i achieve that using css/less/media queries or what am i doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you must use a `min-device-width`. Look here at the table http://viewportsizes.com/?filter=ipad. So a `768px` would work!

Comment: I hope this link may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile

Comment: Thank you setting min-width worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Ashish and @DOC ASAREL, setting min-width did the trick.

This is the solution:

```
@media (min-width: 1281px)  {
            &:hover {
                color: red !important;
                border: 3px solid red !important;
            }
        }
```